# Records issue using top keyword in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Linq query which is working fine but i have noticed when i use take keyword with that query it does not return the same top selected records. 
When i saw the Sql profiler query they are totally same excepts just top keyword in that what may be the problem. One more thing i have noticed is when i give a no greater then records in database it works fine with take as well.

I am attaching the query and records attachment

[image]

and when I apply top 10 in this query it shows this records

[image]

What could be the problem im using Sql Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Using `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` doesn't produce predictable results... if you want to `TOP 10` - you **must** define what the sort criteria is supposed to be! Otherwise: what are the `TOP 10` .....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `TOP` keyword without ordering does not guarantee repeatability of resultset.

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187043.aspx)

> If a SELECT statement that includes TOP also has an ORDER BY clause,
>   the rows to be returned are selected from the ordered result set. The
>   whole result set is built in the specified order and the top n rows in
>   the ordered result set are returned.

Answer (score 3):

Try forcing the query to order the records by using `ORDER BY` (or `orderby` in linq).

Answer (score 3):

The default ordering may differ, try explicitly ordering by a column.